# JNI crash when CallVoidMethod to java function to handler

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When calling my JNI function CallVoidMethod for my UDP program, my program crashes.  I'm having trouble deciphering the problem from the logcat.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code snippets:

JNI function:

```
jmethodID constructID, methodID;
JNIEnv* env;
jclass clazz;
JavaVM *g_jm;
int downLoad_speed_test_start(JNIEnv * envl, jobject thiz, int serverport) {
        jobject obj;


    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, clientAddr;
    int slen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    char buf[512];
    int socket_ovdp;
    if ((socket_ovdp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG",
                "\nSocket() unsuccessful\n");
    else
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG",
                "\nServer: Socket() successful\n");

    bzero(&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(serverport);
    inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        clazz=env->GetObjectClass(thiz);
        constructID = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>","()V");
        methodID = env->GetMethodID(clazz,"jniCall","(I)V");
        obj=env->NewObject(clazz,constructID);
        JavaVM *jm;
        env->GetJavaVM(&jm);

    if (bind(socket_ovdp, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == -1)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG",
                "\nServer : bind() failed!\n");

    else
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG",
                "\nServer : bind() successful\n");
    }

    while (true) {
        if (recvfrom(socket_ovdp, buf, 512, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr,
                &slen) == -1)
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG",
                    "\nRecvfrom() did not work\n");
        else
        {
        //handle message
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG", "\nReceived: %s\n\n",
                buf);
            int newbuf = 5;
            env->CallVoidMethod(obj,methodID,newbuf);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Java function to handler:

```
void jniCall(int arg)
    {

        Message m = mHandler.obtainMessage();
        m.arg1=arg;
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(m, 10/* ms */);
        }

public Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            try{
                chatbox.setText("Got it!");
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("MYLOG", "Message was not handled.");
            }
            //chatbox.setText(chatbox.getText() + "Got it!");
        }
    };
```

My logcat:

```
08-20 18:09:26.200: W/dalvikvm(3521): JNI WARNING: threadid=15 using env from threadid=16
08-20 18:09:26.200: W/dalvikvm(3521):              in Lcom/WifiSpeedTest2/WifiSpeedTestActivity;.ovt_downLoad_speed_test_start:(I)I (CallVoidMethodV)
08-20 18:09:26.210: I/dalvikvm(3521): "Thread-154" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
08-20 18:09:26.210: I/dalvikvm(3521):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40d332f8 self=0x2a1b96f0
08-20 18:09:26.221: I/dalvikvm(3521):   | sysTid=3555 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=706079760
08-20 18:09:26.221: I/dalvikvm(3521):   | state=R schedstat=( 7136784 37413210 12 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
08-20 18:09:26.250: I/Thread:(3521): connected lost
08-20 18:09:26.380: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #00  pc 000012a0  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
08-20 18:09:26.411: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #01  pc 0005faa8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+35)
08-20 18:09:26.411: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #02  pc 00053914  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+303)
08-20 18:09:26.420: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #03  pc 000539ae  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
08-20 18:09:26.420: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #04  pc 00038aba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-20 18:09:26.430: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #05  pc 0003fc24  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-20 18:09:26.430: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #06  pc 0000150c  /data/app-lib/com.WifiSpeedTest2-2/libwifiSpeedTest2.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+60)
08-20 18:09:26.430: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #07  pc 00001c18  /data/app-lib/com.WifiSpeedTest2-2/libwifiSpeedTest2.so (ovt_downLoad_speed_test_start(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int)+956)
08-20 18:09:26.430: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #08  pc 00001e64  /data/app-lib/com.WifiSpeedTest2-2/libwifiSpeedTest2.so (ovt_downLoad_speed_test_start_jni(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int)+72)
08-20 18:09:26.441: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #09  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #10  pc 0004d1f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+391)
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #11  pc 00038b44  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+7)
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #12  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #13  pc 0002b540  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #14  pc 0005f9d4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #15  pc 0005f9fe  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+19)
08-20 18:09:26.470: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #16  pc 00054576  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-20 18:09:26.481: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #17  pc 0000e3b8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
08-20 18:09:26.481: I/dalvikvm(3521):   #18  pc 0000dab0  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
08-20 18:09:26.481: I/dalvikvm(3521):   at com.WifiSpeedTest2.WifiSpeedTestActivity.ovt_downLoad_speed_test_start(Native Method)
08-20 18:09:26.491: I/dalvikvm(3521):   at com.WifiSpeedTest2.WifiSpeedTestActivity$receiveVideoThread.run(WifiSpeedTestActivity.java:96)
08-20 18:09:26.500: E/dalvikvm(3521): VM aborting
08-20 18:09:26.500: A/libc(3521): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 3555 (Thread-154)
```

EDIT: Adding OnLoad and other function

```
int downLoad_speed_test_start_jni(JNIEnv * envl, jobject thiz,
        int serverport) {

    env = envl;
    //env->GetJavaVM(&g_jm);
    downLoad_speed_test_start(env, thiz, serverport);
}


jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)

{

    jint result = -1;
    g_jm = vm;

    // catched_jvm = vm;
    LOGE("JNI_OnLoad\n");
    static const char* const strClassName =
            "com/WifiSpeedTest2/WifiSpeedTestActivity";
    //static const char* const strClassName = "com/MultPkg/Mult";

    if (vm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {

        LOGE("ERROR: GetEnv failed\n");

        return result;

    }

    if (env == NULL) {

        LOGE("ERROR: env is NULL\n");

        return result;

    }

    /* find the class handle */

    clazz = env->FindClass(strClassName);

    if (clazz == NULL) {

        LOGE("Can't find class %s\n", strClassName);

        return result;

    }

    // fields.clazz = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(clazz);

    /* register all the methods */

    if (env->RegisterNatives(clazz, gMethods,
            sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])) != JNI_OK)

    {

        LOGE("Failed registering methods for %s\n", strClassName);

        return result;

    }

    /* success -- return valid version number */

    result = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MY_TAG",
                        "\nJNI OnLoad worked.\n");
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JNI WARNING: threadid=15 using env from threadid=16
```

You're sharing a `JNIEnv` between threads.  Don't do that -- `JNIEnv` is thread-specific.

Either use what is passed in as the first argument to native methods called from Java code, or save off the `JavaVM` in a global and get the the `JNIEnv` with the [GetEnv call](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#GetEnv).

See also the [JNI Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) page.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify what you mean by "Either use what is passed in as the first argument to native methods called from Java code"?  I would like to try to implement that option but am not really understanding it.

Comment: You have a global JNIEnv called "env" that you are using instead of the JNIEnv passed as the first argument to `downLoad_speed_test_start` ("envl").  My guess is that, while you're in the `while (true)` loop, another thread is replacing "env" with its own thread-local JNIEnv.  At that point the function fails.  Get rid of the global "env" -- JNIEnv should never be held in global state -- rename the "envl" argument to "env", fix whatever code was using the global "env", and it should work.

Comment: I added in two more functions of what I have if you want to take a look at it.  I actually think it's using the second option you mentioned with the global.  Aren't I correctly passing the env to my `download_speed_test_start` function?

Comment: You're passing it in, but you aren't using it.  Your code is using the global "env" instead of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna use `JNIEnv`, you must call `AttachCurrentThread()` in your thread to attach itself to the VM and obtain a JNI interface pointer. Here is [Oracle's JNI reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp1060)